# A request made in Go lang gets blocked when Python requests and Curl works

Tags: go, http, web, screen-scraping, user-agent

I am making web scraper with golang, with the http package. I sent a GET request but it gets blocked by Cloudflare. I've wanted to port my tools over to Go but every time I try to, I get stuck at making proper web requests. Here is an example user agent that I use for both Python 3 requests module, curl, httpx, and command line tools.
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36"

Setting the User agent for curl, wget, Python requests like this works perfectly and will return the html body just as expected but when I do the exact same thing in Go-lang, it gives the typical "no-javascript" and enable cookies response body. Here is my Go code, I have also tried quite a few other methods and solutions I found here on SO but they are terribly outdated or provide no real answer other than "try a proxy." which is not a proper solution. (updated code)

```
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    reader, err := gzip.NewReader(r)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer reader.Close()
    buff, err := io.ReadAll(reader)
    return buff, err
}

func main() {
    // url := "https://www.reaperscans.com"
    url := "http://localhost:8000"
    // agent := "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    agent := "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0"
    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // req.Header.Set("User-Agent", agent)
    // req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    // req.Header.Set("Accept", "*/*")
    // req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header = http.Header{
        "User-Agent":      {agent},
        "Accept-Encoding": {"gzip, deflate"},
        "Accept":          {"*/*"},
        "Connection":      {"keep-alive"},
    }

    // make the http request
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // fmt.Println(resp.Uncompressed)

    // body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    // if err != nil {
    //  log.Fatalln(err)
    // }
    // log.Println(string(body))

    // decompress the response
    reader, err := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer reader.Close()

    // read the decompressed resp body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // print it out bb
    fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```

and this is my python code

```
import requests

request_headers = { 
'User-Agent' : ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36'), } 
request = requests.get("https://www.asurascans.com", headers=request_headers)
print(request.text)
```

It also works with curl

> curl -A "blahblah" https://www.asurascans.com > output.html

Yes, you can literally just use "blah" as a user agent and get a successful request. So I'm somewhat baffled that I cannot do this in Go-lang.

I really want to learn to use Go but I coudn't find any working solutions for this basic block to getting off of the ground.

There were some specialized packages that Im not keen on using as they shouldn't be necessary, they aren't liable to still work and I'm not wanting to bypass cloudflare beyond using a user-agent, which works well in Python, wget and Curl.

Any advice on what I can do here?

Update:

- running a Python simple server to echo back headers for debugging as suggested. I was able to tweak my golang headers to match exactly with Python Requests module and Curl, yet the issue persists. I can even use comically bad headers with Curl and Python and it will work, but nothing works with go lang.

Works (curl):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2023 13:03:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR:root:Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: UWU
Accept: */*
X-Something: yeah
```

literally this works and gives me the response text from the exact same website that Go is having trouble with

Works (python):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2023 13:04:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR:root:Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Connection: keep-alive
```

Doesnt work (Go-Lang):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2023 13:06:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ERROR:root:Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is why I am confused

edit:-
ended up taking 6 months but I spent that time learning and came up with this:

```
func tls_request() *http.Client {
    var (
        conn *tls.Conn
        err  error
    )

    tlsConfig := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig

    c := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSHandshakeTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
            DisableKeepAlives:   false,

            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                CipherSuites: []uint16{
                    tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,
                    tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    tls.TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
                    tls.VersionTLS13,
                    tls.VersionTLS10,
                },
            },
            DialTLS: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
                conn, err = tls.Dial(network, addr, tlsConfig)
                return conn, err
            },
        },
    }

    // returns client with the necessary setup bypass basic cloudflare checks
    return c
}
```

full solution here:
https://github.com/sweetbbak/go-cloudflare-bypass/blob/main/reqwest/reqwest.go

Comment: 1) Try exactly the same user-agent. 2) Dump and compare your complete request headers.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful for debugging, however the issue persists. Even if the headers are the exact same, it still only doesn't work for go.

Comment: I've added updated examples to my posts body of the headers that are working in Curl and Python but not in Go

Comment: What is the actual URL that you are fetching?  Is it https://www.reaperscans.com as in the Go program comment or https://www.asurascans.com as in the Python code?

Comment: I've written scrapers in Python for both that dump the front page and parse the links to check for new content, and then return that info in Json format. So I guess starting with asurascans.com is fine but I would like to move on to reaperscans.com if I can get a working solution in Go

Comment: I was just testing both of them out because they both have the same simple cloudflare check for a proper user-agent. Its a pretty common requirement now, very few sites will work without proper headers as far as Im aware

Comment: What's the error message from your Go code?

Comment: There is no error, the issue is that the request is getting blocked by the website. I explained above that, Curl and Python Requests work when making the same request using the standard GET methods + using a custom User-Agent. However in Go, it doesn't. I get "No javascript" errors and I'm guessing it has something to do with TLS / JA3 fingerprinting based purely on what Ive read trying to understand whats happening

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Which Go version are you using? All the ciphers you specify seem to be handled out-of-the-box with Go 1.21.4.

Comment: Go 1.21.4-1 which is the latest version. I think TLS 13 Ciphers - TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 tlsv1.3 are the most important, I dont think they are included by default... and Im not really even bypassing actual cloudflare captchas, just the basic checks so I can request most normal sites.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the cloudflare caught you for faking the browser or imtating like one isnt it ? So you have an app with an http client which uses the user agent of an actual browser. Definitely cloudflare waf will complain.

Instead use a custom user agent for your app so it looks genuine to the CF. Say 'my app 1.0"

Comment: I came up with a solution here https://github.com/sweetbbak/go-cloudflare-bypass/blob/main/reqwest/reqwest.go it was as I said, Go didnt already have a bunch of TLS ciphers baked in that are required for most sites these days.